# react-native/expo: Live Reload / Hot Reload unavailable

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, livereload

When I open the developer menu with expo, it says:

`Live Reload unavailable`

and

`Hot Reloading unavailable`

I am signed in as is needed, I have also tried using the QR code to load the app, but it didn't help.

**.expo/settings.json:**

```
{
  "hostType": "lan",
  "lanType": "ip",
  "dev": true,
  "minify": false,
  "urlRandomness": "8s-6z3"
}
```

There is this, https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1210, but I am not using the `Expo XDE`.

I also tried:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

and:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f yarn.lock
yarn upgrade
yarn
npm install
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer OP directly as his query is quite different:
In my case the problem was I by mistake turned on the production mode so unchecking it helped me get hot-reloading working again:

[image: Image showing the location of production]

Answer (score 1):

[image: react-native expo screenshot]

In my case i use tunnel. this works for me.  `android device` <- `mac`

Answer (score 0):

It just randomly started working, I kept using the `Refresh` option in the developer menu to reload `Expo`.

I always left Expo open after terminating `expo start`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build mode. The fast reloading is available only in **development mode**. If you are in **production mode**, press `p` in the terminal using the `expo-cli` to toggle it back to **development mode**.